# Split plus or minus into list

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like

```
x= 2 \[PlusMinus] Sqrt[3]
```

to evaluate to

```
{x=2+Sqrt[3],x=2-Sqrt[3]}
```

Including any number of plus or minus symbols, so

```
x=(2 \[PlusMinus] Sqrt[3]) \[PlusMinus] 3
```

would evaluation to

```
{x=5+Sqrt[3],x=5-Sqrt[3],x=-1+Sqrt[3],x=-1-Sqrt[3]}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Does this work in every case you can think of?

```
Flatten[{2 \[PlusMinus] Sqrt[3],a \[PlusMinus] 4,
  a \[PlusMinus] b \[PlusMinus] q}//.h__ \[PlusMinus] t__->{h+t,h-t}]
```

which returns

```
{2+Sqrt[3],2-Sqrt[3],4+a,-4+a,a+b+q,a-b+q,a+b-q,a-b-q}]
```

The h__ matches everything before \[PlusMinus], the t__ matches everything after, and the //. repeatedly turns any item that matches into two items until it is done and finally the Flatten discards any introduced { and }.

Preserving the x= in the output is a different issue and is trying to avoid the usual evaluation process. I don't see a simple way of doing that in every case. Perhaps someone else can show a clever way of doing that.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[expandPlusMinus]
expandPlusMinus = Flatten @* ReplaceAll[PlusMinus -> ({+##, # - #2} &)];
```

***Examples:***

```
2 ± Sqrt[3] // expandPlusMinus
```

> ```
> {2 + Sqrt[3], 2 - Sqrt[3]}
> ```

```
(2 ± Sqrt[3]) ± 3 // expandPlusMinus
```

> ```
> {5 + Sqrt[3], 5 - Sqrt[3], -1 + Sqrt[3], -1 - Sqrt[3]}
> ```

```
2 ± Sqrt[3] // expandPlusMinus // Map[PromptForm[x, #] &]
```

[image]

```
(2 ± Sqrt[3]) ± 3 // expandPlusMinus //  Map[PromptForm[x, #] &]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[expandPlusMinus2]
expandPlusMinus2 = Block[{PlusMinus = Flatten@Through[{Plus, Subtract}@##] &}, #] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
2 ± Sqrt[3] // expandPlusMinus2
```

> ```
> {2 + Sqrt[3], 2 - Sqrt[3]}
> ```

```
(2 ± Sqrt[3]) ± 3 // expandPlusMinus2
```

> ```
> {5 + Sqrt[3], 5 - Sqrt[3], -1 + Sqrt[3], -1 - Sqrt[3]}
> ```